# How to check out all VB6 Project files from VSS?

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

I have a VB6 project in Visual Source Safe 6.0. When I open the project I want to Check Out (Get) all the files in the project so that I can edit them.

I have the VSS Options (within VB6) set to act on the Project recursively, but when I check out the project.vbp it only checks out the project file, not all the modules, etc.  Those files all remain write protected until I individually check out each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Select the *Project.vbp* and, from the Tool>SourceSafe menu choose Check Out, you get a dialog which lets you choose ALL files (you get a checkbox for each and a button for Select All).

**Why I had problems**

For some reason, if you *right-click* on the Project in the Project tree and choose Check Out it doesn't give you that dialog. It just checks out the Project file. (However, if you do the same thing and Check In, it gives you the dialog with the checkboxes for each file. I guess that that point it *knows* that you have more than one file to check in.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW generally speaking you get more options when choosing 'Check out...' via the Tools menu as compared with choosing 'Check out' from the right click context menu.  One of the more useful 'Advanced' options is to check out with out 'getting' (i.e. replacing) your local file.